# appendChild() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, appendchild

I tried a little pen on codepen.io (here is [mine <3)](http://codepen.io/Show/),

Here is the code:

```
  var body = $('body');
  var container = document.getElementsByTagName("container");

  var tileTab = new Array(); 

  var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

  var nbTileWidth = Math.floor(windowWidth / 50) - 1;
  var nbTileHeight = Math.floor(windowHeight / 50) - 1;
  var x = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < nbTileHeight; i++){

    var row = document.createElement("div");

    for(var j = 0; j < nbTileWidth; j++){

      tileTab[x] = document.createElement("div");
      row.appendChild(tileTab[x]);
      tileTab[x].className = "tile";
      x++;

    }
    container.appendChild(row);
    row.className = "row";
  }
  body.appendChild(container);
```

This pen is available here : [codepen](http://codepen.io/Show/pen/YWKzLa)

Console return me

```
container.appendChild is not a function
```

I tried it with jQuery but it's the same :/.

Sorry to post this, it seems to be a basic issue but now i don't know what's wrong here. Ty in advance!

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("container");`? There's no `<container>` in HTML. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Comment: var container = document.getElementsByTagName("container")[0]; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName This method return array-like object....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace these lines:

```
var body = $('body');
var container = document.getElementsByTagName("container");
```

with these:

```
var body = document.body;
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
```